# How to swap an integer array's value and index in vb macro

Tags: vba

How to swap an integer array's value and index in vb macro

```
i(0 to 5) = {3,4,1,5,0,2}
To
i(0 to 5) = {4,2,5,0,1,3}
```

editing...

Thankyou @Tim and @Cody

The following function is what i have got, but looking for better and more efficent ways to do it with/without the array l_aiOldIndexSwap

```
    Public Function SortValuePairs(ByRef l_aiValues() As Integer) As Integer()
     Dim l_aiOldIndexSwap() As Integer
     ReDim l_aiOldIndexSwap(LBound(l_aiValues) To UBound(l_aiValues))
     For i = LBound(l_aiValues) To UBound(l_aiValues)
      l_aiOldIndexSwap(l_aiValues(i)) = i
     Next
     SortValuePairs = l_aiOldIndexSwap
    End Function
```

Comment: What algorithm are you using to perform the swap depicted in the example?

Comment: I am not using any algorithm as such for this, but if you can guide me to any of such algos it would be nice :)

Comment: Oops, I might have misled you with the "swap" keyword. Sorry, I was not sure which keywords to use for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim Result As Integer()
ReDim Result(5)
For iLoop = 0 To 5
    Result(i(iLoop)) = iLoop
Next
```

Comment: To make code format as code, just indent each line with 4 spaces, or select the entire block and click the `{}` button in the toolbar. Yeah, VB doesn't have any curly braces, but good icons are hard to come by!

Comment: Thankyou, Is it possible to accomplish the same without the array i()